# List of <MatofPoints> array in Android

Tags: java, android, arrays, list, opencv

I am creating OMR scanner in java.
I have List of  which contains contours from image. 
i want to create array of List. how can i accomplish it?

this is what i have right now

```
List<MatOfPoint> questions = new ArrayList<MatOfPoint>();
```

What i want to do is

```
List<MatOfPoint>[] questions = new ArrayList<MatOfPoint>[];
```

so that i can store array of countours() for each question.
Like

[1] contour1,contour2,contour3,contour4,contour5

[2] contour1,contour2,contour3,contour4,contour5

[3] contour1,contour2,contour3,contour4,contour5

...............................

Comment: And what seems to be the issue?

Comment: why not a list of lists?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably better to just use a list of list. But you can do something like this:

```
List<MatOfPoint>[] questions = (ArrayList<MatOfPoint>[]) new ArrayList[n];
```